# Importing api has duplicate signature operations azure web api

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, azure-api-management

I am trying to import my swagger schema to azure APIM but it keeps giving me duplicate signature error.

> Importing API has duplicate signature operations: 2 operations with signature 'GET /api/v1/brokers/{brokerid}'; 2 operations with signature 'GET /api/v1/marketreport/{brokerid}'; 2 operations with signature 'GET /api/v1/offices/{officeid}'; 2 operations with signature 'GET /api/v1/teams/{teamid}'`

I have double-checked my API routes and swagger schema but can't see any duplications. This schema update was working fine before May 11, 2018 azure api updates.

I have read the [release notes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/apimanagement/2018/05/11/azure-api-management-release-notes-may-11-2018/) but couldn't find anything. My endpoints look like this.

```cs
    [Route("{officeId:int:min(1)}", Name = "GetOfficeById")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetOfficeById(int officeId, [FromUri] IncludeImageModel includeImage)
    
    [Route("{brokerId:int:min(1)}", Name = "GetBrokerById")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetBrokerById(int brokerId, [FromUri] IncludeImageModel includeImage)
    
    [Route("{teamId:int:min(1)}", Name = "GetTeamById")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetTeamById(int teamId, [FromUri] IncludeImageModel includeImage)
    
    [Route("MarketReport/{brokerId:int}", Name = "GetMarketReportsByBrokerId")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetMarketReportsByBrokerId(int brokerId, [FromUri]CBBainApi.Models.Common common)
```

Comment: Could you share all paths from your swagger file? Or maybe file itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by reading the `Path template validation changes` part from the [Release notes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/apimanagement/2018/05/11/azure-api-management-release-notes-may-11-2018/).
As it states to 'improve deduplication logic' they have added normalization steps prior to checking for uniqueness:

If the path template contains a query string, all segments after `?` delimited with `&` character are sorted in alphabetical, case-insensitive order (without any special handling for `=` character).

That means if you have two endpoints like bellow

```cs
    [RoutePrefix("brokers")]
    public class BrokerController : ApiController
    
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{brokerId:int:min(1)}", Name = "GetBrokerById")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetBrokerById(int brokerId, [FromUri] IncludeImageModel includeImage)
    
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{webUrl}", Name = "GetBrokerByWebUrl")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetBrokerByWebUrl(string webUrl, [FromUri] IncludeImageModel includeImage)
```

this APIM will check for uniqueness by converting them into like:

`"brokers/{brokerId:int:min(1)}"` to `"brokers/{0}"` and `"brokers/{webUrl}"` to `"brokers/{0}"`

and will give a duplicate signature error.

Both endpoints are being used in mobile apps so I had no option to alter the routes, so I merged by both endpoints to

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{param}", Name = "GetBroker")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetBroker(string param, [FromUri] IncludeImageModel includeImage)
          {
             int brokerId = default(int);
             if (int.TryParse(param, out brokerId))
                 ... do something
             else
                 ...do something else
            //return something;
        }
```